# Magento OnepageController overwrite breaking checkout

Tags: magento

**In brief:** Made overrides to one page cart controller and clicking on 'checkout' in front end no longer redirects you to checkout/onepage/

**The details:** I'm trying to override some of the OnepageController functionality - essentially so it will always go from the billing tab to the shipping tab, wherein I can ask for some extra shipping-related information that's used to calculate, well, shipping rates.

So, here's the config.xml bit:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <CodexMedia_SmartSend before="Mage_Checkout">
                    CodexMedia_SmartSend
                    </CodexMedia_SmartSend>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

.. which uses a new OnepageController instance (located in CodexMedia/SmartSend/controllers/OnepageController.php) that extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController) This controller only has the saveBillingAction() modded to always push out the shipping tab and not go straight to Payment Information (I will be adding custom saveShippingAction logic when I get this working properly).

My best guess is I've binked some kind of routing

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT:** Moved the controller to controllers/Checkout, changing the class to CodexMedia_SmartSend_Checkout_Onepagecontroller and changing config to:

```
        <checkout>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <CodexMedia_SmartSend_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">CodexMedia_SmartSend_Checkout</CodexMedia_SmartSend_Checkout>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
```

Bingo! All good. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the newline between CodexMedia_SmartSend tag.The config file should be as follows

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <CodexMedia_SmartSend before="Mage_Checkout">CodexMedia_SmartSend</CodexMedia_SmartSend>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

Comment: ahh, good to know that's pertienent - however I added the sapce in the question for clarity, whups :) I've since tweaked it - here's how that middle config tag looks now: <CodexMedia_SmartSend_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">CodexMedia_SmartSend_Checkout</CodexMedia_SmartSend_Checkout>